# Append elements to list within an array of lists

Tags: r

I have an array of lists:

```
M <- array(list(numeric(2)), 5)

> M
[[1]]
[1] 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0

[[5]]
[1] 0 0
```

I want to append to those lists vectors of a fixed length, for example 2, like this one

```
x = as.numeric(1:2)
```

I tried

```
> M[1][2] = x
Warning messages:
1: In M[1][2] = x :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In M[1][2] = x :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> M[1]
[[1]]
[1] 0 0
```

and

```
> M[1][[2]] = x
Warning message:
In M[1][[2]] = x :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
> M[1]
[[1]]
[1] 0 0
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
 > M[1]
    [[1]]
    [1] 0 0
    [[2]]
    [1] 1 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe `lapply(M, function(i) c(i, x))` ?

Comment: Or you want to add to the first list: `M[[ 1 ]][1:2] <- x` ?

Comment: I want to have 5 lists of vectors, so I can add vectors to those lists

Comment: The codes you commented only add the vector the the first element of each list, I need to add a vector to be the second, third, etc., element of the lists, that's my problem

Comment: Can you edit your post and show your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
M[[1]] <- list(M[[1]], x)

M[1]
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 0 0

#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this on the fly with `modifyList` after setting the names

```
names(M) <- seq_along(M)
modifyList(M, list(`1` = list(M[[1]], x)))
```